# SwiftUI tabItem with system Image resizing with accessibility

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am creating a new iOS app with SwiftUI and have a TabView where I am using the calendar system image for the Image in a tabItem. When I turn on accessibility and increase or decrease the font size, the calendar system image also resizes.

In the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sf-symbols/overview/) for SF Symbols it says you can use system images in Tab Bars and I assume they are encouraged to also be used in the SwiftUI representation of Tab Bars i.e. TabViews.

However, I am unable to prevent the system image from resizing. Does anyone know how to?

```
TabView {
    Text("Example")
        .tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "calendar")
            Text("Example")
        }
}
```

Below show's a screenshot with the dynamic font set at its largest size

[image: Largest Accessibility Font Used]

Comment: In a fact it looks like a defect, so I'd recommend to submit it to Apple.

Comment: did you ever solve this?